# How to convert data from json to List<Object> in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I need to obtain a list of Articles(a custom object) from a realtime database in Firebase. I first decode my data from a json data type. Then I try to convert it into a list using this line of code:

```
List<Article> articles = List<Article>.from(articleResponse)
  .map((Map model) => Article.fromJson(model))
  .toList();
```

However, this gives a syntax error of "The argument type 'Article Function(Map<dynamic,dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Article)'." I have included the code I use to fetch an Article(the custom object) as well as the factory method for the class.

```
//Method to get articles
Future<List<Article>> fetchArticles() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      "https://some-server.firebaseio.com/some-url.json");
  final articleResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  List<Article> articles = List<Article>.from(articleResponse)
      .map((Map model) => Article.fromJson(model))
      .toList(); // Now we're looping over the response entries (maps of article info) to create Article instances
  return articles;
}
```

```
\\Factory Method
factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      author: json['author'],
      date: json['date'],
      imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],
      modalities: json['modalities'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make an example with something like a json response.

```
void main() {
  //this is an example like a json response
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> articleResponse = [
    {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"test1"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "name":"test2"
    }
  ];
  List<Article> articles = List<Article>.from(articleResponse.map((Map art)=>Article.fromJson(art)))
     .toList();
  
  print('${articles.length} articles in the list!! use to render de ui list');
}

class Article{
  String id;
  String name;
  Article({this.id,this.name});
  
  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

basically you need to change your method to get articles with  this.

```
//Method to get articles
Future<List<Article>> fetchArticles() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      "https://some-server.firebaseio.com/some-url.json");
  final articleResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  List<Article> articles = List<Article>.from(articleResponse.map((Map art)=>Article.fromJson(art)))
     .toList(); // Now we're looping over the response entries (maps of article info) to create Article instances
  return articles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[JsonToDart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)**

this is create a class for parse your complex json data

**paste json and get class of model**

Answer (score 0):

you can overrride toString in your model like:

```
    @override
  String toString() {
    return '{
      id: $id, 
      title: $title, 
      author: $author, 
      date: $date, 
      imageUrl: $imageUrl, 
      modalities: $modalities
    }';
  }
```

and override toMap :

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'author': author,
      'date': date,
      'imageUrl': imageUrl,
      'modalities': modalities,
    };
  }
```

---

and you can use serialization that. [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) can help you